# TypeScript - prevent from inserting magic code - how?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am VERY green with regard to TypeScript (so be kind), but I have been unable to figure out how to stop TypeScript from adding what appears to be "magic" code to the resulting Javascript after transpiling.

Whenever I use "tsc", no errors are reported, but Typescript appends the following as the last line in the Javasccript file:

```
export {};
```

... and when the Javascript file is executed (loaded in a browser) this results in the following error being reported by the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

The compiler options in tsconfig.json are:

```
"compilerOptions": {
     "target": "ES2015",
     "removeComments": false,
     "noImplicitAny": true,
     "noImplicitThis": true,
     "moduleResolution": "Node"
   },
```

I then try changing the compiler options to the following:

```
   "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "ES2015",
     "module":"CommonJS",
     "removeComments": false,
     "noImplicitAny": true,
     "noImplicitThis": true,
     "moduleResolution": "Node"
   },
```

Success - the export line is no longer present, but now, the following line is added to the top of the javascript file!:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

... and (again) when the Javascript file is executed (loaded in a browser) this results in the following error being reported by the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

I also tried to change the script tag that loads the javascript produced by tsc to make use of type="module", i.e.:

```
<script type="module" src="file_produced_by_tsc.js"></script>
```

... **when the page is loaded locally**, the console displays:

Access to script at 'file:///...' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

```
Access to script at 'file:///...' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Obviously, the browser is telling me the script cannot be loaded locally, but I typically do my JS debugging that way. It would be a royal pain to have to upload the script just to load it from a network resource!

Good grief -- all I want is the Javascript code WITHOUT any "magic code" added.  A compiler option such as:

```
"excludeMagicCode": true
```

... would be ideal!

Obviously, I am missing something very basic; is there a compiler option that can prevent these magic code statements from littering the resulting Javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After doing a bit of searching, I found [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39446) which seems to say TypeScript's compiler isn't meant to generate non-module code on its own. You could try using TypeScript alongside a module bundler, like Webpack for example, in order to generate non-module JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research and reading about [this similar issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41513), it appears that tsc is doing its job, but the real issue (for me) is using (loading) the resulting Javascript locally; which could not be done.

Since I am using Visual Studio Code, I created a Powershell script (fix_files.ps1) within the project folder to remove the export statements from the Javascript tsc produces:

```
#
# Remove all lines from the given file that start
# with the given string ...
#
function remove_lines( [string]$file_spec, [string]$remove_str="export {" ) {

   #
   # A file spec is required ...
   #

   if ( [String]::IsNullOrEmpty( $file_spec ) ) {

      Write-Output "* File specification is required"

      return

   }

   #
   # String to remove is required ...
   #
   
   if ( [String]::IsNullOrEmpty( $remove_str ) ) {

       Write-Output "* String to remvoe is required"

       return

   }

   #
   # Exit if file not found ...
   #
   
   if ( -not [System.IO.File]::Exists( $file_spec ) ) {

      Write-Output "* File not found: $file_spec"

      return

   }

   #
   # Count the number of lines that start with the given string
   # and if any are found, remove those lines from the file ...
   #

   $line_count = Get-Content $file_spec | Where { $_.StartsWith( $remove_str ) } | Measure-Object

   if ( $line_count.Count -gt 0 ) {

      (get-content $file_spec) | Where { -not $_.StartsWith( $remove_str ) } | Set-Content $file_spec

   }

   Write-Output "- $file_spec, lines removed: $($line_count.Count)"

}

#
# Fix files ...
#

Write-Output "Fixing Javascript files:"

remove_lines( "file1.js" )
remove_lines( "file2.js" )
```

Using the Terminal in Visual Studio Code, I run the following commands:

```
> tsc
> .\fix_files.ps1
```

Not very elegant, but at least it allows me to develop locally without the need for a module bundler or setting up a local web host.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `"module":"CommonJS"` you are telling TypeScript to generate Node.js-like JavaScript, which is passed properties from its wrapping function arguments on execution such as `exports` (hence why it added code expecting it).

By default, TypeScript is generating JavaScript to be EcmaScript6-module compliant **however** the HTML `script` tag doesn't try to read modular JavaScript by default. One thing you can try, after you remove the module config setting and rebuild, is add the `type` attribute with the value `module` explicitly in your HTML:

```
 <script type="module" src="./ts-build-example.js"></script>
```

This will allow the script to accept and run `export` (and `import`) statements in most modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I updated the OP to include the case where the script tag includes type="module" -- still no luck.   The only "solution" I have currently, is to comment out the magic code inserted by tsc !

Comment: And you're not compiling to CommonJs anymore when trying that?

Comment: With or without CommonJs, tsc inserts code that makes the Javascript unusable (when being loaded locally) -- currently, I have a note at the top of the .ts file to "Comment out the following line inserted by tsc..." - a royal pain, but at least I can test until a solution is found.